# Which approach is better in terms of performance while querying mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two collections. One is **students** and the other is **books**. Students may select up to 100 books.  So, I may design students collection as

```
{
'_id'=>'',
 selections['bookid1', 'bookid2', 'bookid3' ... so on]
}
```

And another solution would be a selections collections

```
{
'_id'=>''
'book_id'=>'',
'student_id'=>''
 }
```

Which design is better in terms of query performance.  Is there any other reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: I would tend to the second approach. Why not benchmarking it?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo does not support join. When you are modeling your data there is tips in mongo docs. 
The references in mongo go thought databases but isn't a good approach. The preference is use manual reference. For instance

```
{
  'isbn': '',
  'title': ''
}

{
'name': '',
'books': [isbn numbers... ]

}
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/